# Can't target first link with pseudo classes in bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

Here is my nav bar:

[image]

Each link has 29px padding on the left and right sides. In order to maximise the amount of available space, I'm trying to remove the left padding from the first link and the right padding from the last link.

CSS:

```
.nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 29px;
    padding-right: 29px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.nav > li > a:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.nav > li > a:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

I thought the last two rules would accomplish what I wanted, but instead it just removed the left and right padding from every single element.

Comment: have you tried .nav > li:first-child > a

Comment: oh wow, im an idiot. i get it now. that worked perfectly, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) allow you to apply styles to elements based on various factors, including their relation to the document tree.

From MDN:

> - The [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child)
>     CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child
>     element of its parent.
> - The [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child)
>     CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element
>     of its parent.

In your HTML, the `<a>` element appears to be nested alone, as a child of each `<li>` element. Hence, when you apply your code...

```
.nav > li > a:first-child { padding-left: 0px; }
.nav > li > a:last-child { padding-right: 0px; }
```

... both `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes match the same, singular `<a>` child of each `<li>`, and the padding is removed across the board.

If you were to have a list of, let's say, five `<a>` elements in each `<li>`, your rules would have removed the padding from the first and last `<a>` in the list for each `<li>`, per the definitions above. Again, not what you wanted.

As mentioned in the comments, to remove the padding from the first and last links alone apply the pseudo-classes to the `<li>` tags instead.

```
.nav > li:first-child > a { padding-left: 0px; }
.nav > li:last-child > a { padding-right: 0px; }
```